# Change main Kodi source

Tags: kodi

**tl;dr** *How to change a Samba source in Kodi that has become invalid, to make it valid again?*

---

I am using Kodi 19.3 Matrix on board Android 11. My entire library is based on a single SMB source in my home network (a NAS drive).

I have updated my NAS' disk. The new one has a different label and thus network path pointing to it has changed a little bit.

How can I edit (or delete) that single source in my Kodi?

No matter where I go (library, settings), no matter what I choose, Kodi is shooting me with errors messages that path is invalid or playing given item has failed. But offers me know way to edit that source.